# Annoying white gap on left side of site

Tags: html, css, styles, margin

I've been trying for the past two hours to get rid of this gap and I've still had no luck :( Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have already correctly linked normalise.css, anytime I try making the margin of the body/header/footer 0 the hr line simply wont move over to the left and neither will the text, it's also making my logo appear slightly off centre as well which is annoying. I have included a picture of what the website looks like for me when I run it.

[PICTURE OF SITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3VgB.jpg)

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

img.center {      /* Centering and styling the logo */
  display: block;
   margin: auto;
   width: 7%;
   padding: 0;
}

ul {               /* Removing the bullet-points and styling the nav bar */
  list-style: none;
}
li {              
   float: left;
}

hr { 
 height: 6px; 
 background-color: #000000; 
 padding: 0;
 margin-left: -8px
 margin: -8px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}

head {
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

footer {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Declaring the document type -->

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/normalise.css"> <!-- creating link element to the normalise.css file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css"> <!-- creating link element to the main.css file --> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <img src="LOGO.png" alt="ANALOG Logo" class="center"> <!-- Adding the logo  -->
   <nav> <!-- indicates that page navigation follows -->
    <ul> <!-- Unorderd list of elements -->
     <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li> <!-- Link to About Us page -->
     <li><a href="venues.html">Venues</a></li> <!-- Link to Venues page -->
     <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li> <!-- Link to Home Page -->
     <li><a href="artists.html">Artists</a></li> <!-- Link to Artists page -->
     <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li> <!-- Link to Contact Us page --> 
    <hr/> <!-- horizontal line across page -->
 </body>










</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues at play here - first the li's are being floated, but the float isn't being cleared - so the hr is sitting in a displaced position. I corrected this by adding a clear:both style rule to the hr.

The other issue is that the ul has padding applied to it by the browner - so i explicitly set the ul padding left to 0. I also added a margin-right to the li's but you may want to use flex to space them out evenly.

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

img.center {      /* Centering and styling the logo */
  display: block;
   margin: auto;
   width: 7%;
   padding: 0;
}

ul {               /* Removing the bullet-points and styling the nav bar */
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
li {              
   float: left;
    margin-right:15px
}

hr { 
 height: 6px; 
 background-color: #000000; 
 padding: 0;
 margin-left: -8px
 margin: -8px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}

head {
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

footer {
 margin: 0;
}

hr {clear:both}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Declaring the document type -->

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/normalise.css"> <!-- creating link element to the normalise.css file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css"> <!-- creating link element to the main.css file --> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <img src="LOGO.png" alt="ANALOG Logo" class="center"> <!-- Adding the logo  -->
   <nav> <!-- indicates that page navigation follows -->
    <ul> <!-- Unorderd list of elements -->
     <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li> <!-- Link to About Us page -->
     <li><a href="venues.html">Venues</a></li> <!-- Link to Venues page -->
     <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li> <!-- Link to Home Page -->
     <li><a href="artists.html">Artists</a></li> <!-- Link to Artists page -->
     <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li> <!-- Link to Contact Us page --> 
    <hr/> <!-- horizontal line across page -->
 </body>










</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` which will reset all the extra margin and padding from all elements on your site. And then only WHEN you need them to be styled, you add something, this would be a good practice! But you can probably do something like `html{margin:0; padding:0;}` which should also be enough for the border around your page. Even if it doesn't solve your issue, it is a good practice to implement what I wrote here.

Also to avoid similar issues in some browsers it is good practice to implement every single detail of your doctype and html tag such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> ... </html>
```